# Unable to locate controller while passing query string

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am preparing a POC to use [IMDB auto complete](http://lab.abhinayrathore.com/imdb_suggest).  I am facing a strange issue. When I enter any keyword, the controller doesn't get call. Here is snippets of javascript and the controller.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){

    $("#q").focus();
    $("#q").autocomplete({

        minLength: 0,
        delay:5,
        source: "suggest",
        focus: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).val( ui.item.value );
            return false;
        }
    }).data("uiAutocomplete")._renderItem = function( ul, item ) {
        //code to render autocomplete list
    };
});
</script>
```

**application/controller/suggest.php**

```
<?php
    $term = trim(strtolower($_REQUEST['term']));
    echo $term;
?>
```

**My url is**
/movies/index.php/suggest?term=g

Would anyone please guide me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try returning a json string from php:

```
$arr = array(
   0 => array(
       'label' => 'item 001',
       'value' => 1
   ),
   1 => array(
       'label' => 'item 002',
       'value' => 2
   ),
   2 => array(
       'label' => 'item 003',
       'value' => 3
   ),
);

echo json_encode($arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

in source just give proper path for suggest controller by adding base_url define a global variable in javascript in base_url before calling script

```
<script>
 var base_url = "<?=base_url()?>";
</script>

source: base_url+"suggest",
```